# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment: SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b2f7e9b2744, pid=28778, tid=1138739520

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, garbage-collection, jvm, glassfish-3

I am getting the following error while executing the program.

And this is not always happening. 
The code contains some complex calculations with a large volume of data.

Could somebody help to identify the error

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00002b2f7e9b2744, pid=28778, tid=1138739520
#
# JRE version: 7.0-b147
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# V  [libjvm.so+0x64e744]  PhaseIdealLoop::clone_loop(IdealLoopTree*, Node_List&, int, Node*)+0xe34
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00002aaab4198000):  JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28799, stack(0x0000000043cfc000,0x0000000043dfd000)]

siginfo:si_signo=SIGSEGV: si_errno=0, si_code=1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr=0x0000000000000008

Registers:
RAX=0x0000000000000000, RBX=0x000000000f2793a0, RCX=0x0000000000004000, RDX=0x0000000000000000
RSP=0x0000000043df8050, RBP=0x0000000043df8170, RSI=0x00002aaab727e610, RDI=0x00002aaab6020d70
R8 =0x00002aaab5ff7519, R9 =0x0000000000004000, R10=0x00002aaab72266c0, R11=0x00002aaab5fe9140
R12=0x00002aaab4d3f7c0, R13=0x0000000000000002, R14=0x000000000c5f76d0, R15=0x0000000043df9bc0
RIP=0x00002b2f7e9b2744, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010202, CSGSFS=0x0000000000000033, ERR=0x0000000000000004
  TRAPNO=0x000000000000000e

Top of Stack: (sp=0x0000000043df8050)
0x0000000043df8050:   00002aaab4d41ea0 0000000043df8120
0x0000000043df8060:   0000000043df8120 0000000000000000
0x0000000043df8070:   0000020043df80a0 0000000043df86e0
0x0000000043df8080:   00002aaab6020d70 00002aaab419c020
0x0000000043df8090:   000038d443df9bc0 0000000000000000
0x0000000043df80a0:   0000000000000000 0000000000000000
0x0000000043df80b0:   00002aaab4d40d78 00002aaab6020d70
0x0000000043df80c0:   00002aaab4d41638 0000020ab4801e80
0x0000000043df80d0:   00002aaab5ff6d18 00002aaab5ff4aa8
0x0000000043df80e0:   00002aaab4d40df8 0000000043df9be0
0x0000000043df80f0:   00002aaab5ff6d20 0000000000000010
0x0000000043df8100:   0000000043df9be0 00002aaab4d41678
0x0000000043df8110:   0000002d0000002d 000002010000002c
0x0000000043df8120:   00002aaab419c020 00002aaa00000008
0x0000000043df8130:   00002aaab5fe9140 00002b2f00000003
0x0000000043df8140:   00002aaab4ff9448 0000000043df9bc0
0x0000000043df8150:   00002aaab4d3ffa8 00002aaab4d3ff40
0x0000000043df8160:   00002aaab4d3fe70 00002aaab4ff9580
0x0000000043df8170:   0000000043df8250 00002b2f7e996ea5
0x0000000043df8180:   0000000043df9be0 01000001c018ba10
0x0000000043df8190:   0000000043df86e0 00002aaab6020d70
0x0000000043df81a0:   0000000043df9bc0 00002aaab4ff94f8
0x0000000043df81b0:   00002aaab4d3f6d8 00002aaab5ff70b8
0x0000000043df81c0:   000000000c5fc740 00002aaab4d3f520
0x0000000043df81d0:   7fffffff00000200 00002aaab4ff9448
0x0000000043df81e0:   00002aaab4d3f4e0 00000003b6020d70
0x0000000043df81f0:   00002aaab4d3fe30 0000000043df9be0
0x0000000043df8200:   000000000b77a070 00002aaab4d3fd48
0x0000000043df8210:   00002aaab4d3fa38 00000001b5ff7500
0x0000000043df8220:   0000000043df86e0 00002aaab6020d70
0x0000000043df8230:   00002aaab4ff9580 0000000043df9bc0
0x0000000043df8240:   0000000043df86e0 0000000000000001 

Instructions: (pc=0x00002b2f7e9b2744)
0x00002b2f7e9b2724:   ff ff 66 2e 0f 1f 84 00 00 00 00 00 89 c0 48 8d
0x00002b2f7e9b2734:   34 c5 00 00 00 00 49 03 b7 e0 09 00 00 48 8b 16
0x00002b2f7e9b2744:   48 8b 42 08 48 83 38 00 75 2b 41 8b 4f 28 66 0f
0x00002b2f7e9b2754:   1f 44 00 00 8b 42 28 31 d2 39 c8 73 0e 89 c2 49 

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000000f2793a0 is an unknown value
RCX=0x0000000000004000 is an unknown value
RDX=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
RSP=0x0000000043df8050 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00002aaab4198000
RBP=0x0000000043df8170 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00002aaab4198000
RSI=0x00002aaab727e610 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00002aaab6020d70 is an unknown value
R8 =0x00002aaab5ff7519 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000000004000 is an unknown value
R10=0x00002aaab72266c0 is an unknown value
R11=0x00002aaab5fe9140 is an unknown value
R12=0x00002aaab4d3f7c0 is an unknown value
R13=0x0000000000000002 is an unknown value
R14=0x000000000c5f76d0 is an unknown value
R15=0x0000000043df9bc0 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00002aaab4198000


Stack: [0x0000000043cfc000,0x0000000043dfd000],  sp=0x0000000043df8050,  free space=1008k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
V  [libjvm.so+0x64e744]  PhaseIdealLoop::clone_loop(IdealLoopTree*, Node_List&, int, Node*)+0xe34
V  [libjvm.so+0x632ea5]  PhaseIdealLoop::do_unroll(IdealLoopTree*, Node_List&, bool)+0x645
V  [libjvm.so+0x6382c9]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split_impl(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0x4b9
V  [libjvm.so+0x638468]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0x148
V  [libjvm.so+0x638418]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0xf8
V  [libjvm.so+0x638418]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0xf8
V  [libjvm.so+0x638418]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0xf8
V  [libjvm.so+0x638418]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0xf8
V  [libjvm.so+0x638418]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0xf8
V  [libjvm.so+0x638418]  IdealLoopTree::iteration_split(PhaseIdealLoop*, Node_List&)+0xf8
V  [libjvm.so+0x645e3c]  PhaseIdealLoop::build_and_optimize(bool)+0x90c
V  [libjvm.so+0x39c36e]  Compile::Optimize()+0x43e
V  [libjvm.so+0x39d96c]  Compile::Compile(ciEnv*, C2Compiler*, ciMethod*, int, bool, bool)+0xdac
V  [libjvm.so+0x312042]  C2Compiler::compile_method(ciEnv*, ciMethod*, int)+0x142
V  [libjvm.so+0x3a2cad]  CompileBroker::invoke_compiler_on_method(CompileTask*)+0x2ed
V  [libjvm.so+0x3a35dd]  CompileBroker::compiler_thread_loop()+0x43d
V  [libjvm.so+0x80d79a]  JavaThread::run()+0x17a
V  [libjvm.so+0x6f84b0]  java_start(Thread*)+0x100


Current CompileTask:
C2: 768101 3793   !         fmi.common.utils.PortfolioEvaluator::CalculateMaxDrawDown (666 bytes)


---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000d858800 JavaThread "Keep-Alive-Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=3547, stack(0x0000000055336000,0x0000000055837000)]
  0x000000000c858800 JavaThread "log-rotation-timer" [_thread_blocked, id=29237, stack(0x0000000049a11000,0x0000000049f12000)]
  0x00002aaab9c97800 JavaThread "Thread-54" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=29089, stack(0x000000004bd18000,0x000000004c219000)]
  0x00002aaab8d6b000 JavaThread "Thread-51" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=29052, stack(0x000000004c71a000,0x000000004cc1b000)]
  0x000000000e630000 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-443(5)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28901, stack(0x000000004900f000,0x0000000049510000)]
  0x000000000e62f000 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-443(4)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28900, stack(0x000000004ea21000,0x000000004ef22000)]
  0x000000000e62e800 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-443(3)" daemon [_thread_in_Java, id=28899, stack(0x0000000049510000,0x0000000049a11000)]
  0x000000000f461000 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-443(2)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28898, stack(0x0000000051229000,0x000000005172a000)]
  0x000000000e21b800 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-443(1)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28897, stack(0x0000000053f32000,0x0000000054433000)]
  0x00002aaac1de5800 JavaThread "pool-7-thread-1" [_thread_blocked, id=28892, stack(0x0000000054e35000,0x0000000055336000)]
  0x00002aaab98f2000 JavaThread "SCR Component Actor" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28890, stack(0x000000004f924000,0x000000004fe25000)]
  0x00002aaab9d72800 JavaThread "fileinstall-/var/glassfish/domains/domain1/autodeploy/bundles/" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28889, stack(0x0000000054433000,0x0000000054934000)]
  0x00002aaab5d66800 JavaThread "RMI RenewClean-[127.0.0.1:8686]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28887, stack(0x0000000053a31000,0x0000000053f32000)]
  0x00002aaab9220000 JavaThread "Configuration Updater" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28886, stack(0x0000000053530000,0x0000000053a31000)]
  0x00002aaab9ed3800 JavaThread "RMI Scheduler(0)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28885, stack(0x000000005302f000,0x0000000053530000)]
  0x00002aaab8d74000 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-80(5)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28884, stack(0x0000000052b2e000,0x000000005302f000)]
  0x00002aaaba5d9800 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-80(4)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28883, stack(0x000000005262d000,0x0000000052b2e000)]
  0x00002aaaba5d8800 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-80(3)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28882, stack(0x000000005212c000,0x000000005262d000)]
  0x00002aaab9497000 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-80(2)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28881, stack(0x0000000051c2b000,0x000000005212c000)]
  0x00002aaab9496000 JavaThread "http-thread-pool-80(1)" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28880, stack(0x000000005172a000,0x0000000051c2b000)]
  0x00002aaab8976800 JavaThread "GC Daemon" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28878, stack(0x0000000050d28000,0x0000000051229000)]
  0x00002aaab8e75000 JavaThread "RMI Reaper" [_thread_blocked, id=28877, stack(0x0000000050827000,0x0000000050d28000)]
  0x000000000ec1b000 JavaThread "RMI TCP Accept-8686" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28876, stack(0x0000000050326000,0x0000000050827000)]
  0x000000000b4e8800 JavaThread "DestroyJavaVM" [_thread_blocked, id=28782, stack(0x00000000402e5000,0x00000000407e6000)]
  0x000000000ee68800 JavaThread "GlassFish Kernel Main Thread" [_thread_blocked, id=28875, stack(0x000000004fe25000,0x0000000050326000)]
  0x00002aaac1dc8000 JavaThread "AutoDeployer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28873, stack(0x000000004f423000,0x000000004f924000)]
  0x00002aaac1104800 JavaThread "DynamicReloader" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28872, stack(0x000000004ef22000,0x000000004f423000)]
  0x00002aaab6288000 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[server].StandardContext[/app.ui.pages]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28869, stack(0x000000004e520000,0x000000004ea21000)]
  0x00002aaab8f1d800 JavaThread "MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28868, stack(0x000000004e01f000,0x000000004e520000)]
  0x00002aaabb002000 JavaThread "Thread-33" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28867, stack(0x000000004db1e000,0x000000004e01f000)]
  0x00002aaab6295800 JavaThread "Thread-32" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28866, stack(0x000000004d61d000,0x000000004db1e000)]
  0x000000000e6ea000 JavaThread "Listener@12172012_012638@56" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28865, stack(0x000000004d11c000,0x000000004d61d000)]
  0x000000000ee22000 JavaThread "Thread-31" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28864, stack(0x000000004cc1b000,0x000000004d11c000)]
  0x00002aaab623b000 JavaThread "Java2D Disposer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28862, stack(0x000000004c219000,0x000000004c71a000)]
  0x00002aaab5064800 JavaThread "deployment-jar-scanner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28848, stack(0x000000004b817000,0x000000004bd18000)]
  0x00002aaab7545800 JavaThread "deployment-jar-scanner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28847, stack(0x000000004b316000,0x000000004b817000)]
  0x000000000d00a800 JavaThread "deployment-jar-scanner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28846, stack(0x000000004ae15000,0x000000004b316000)]
  0x00002aaab7476800 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[glassfish-web].StandardHost[server].StandardContext[/hello]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28845, stack(0x000000004a914000,0x000000004ae15000)]
  0x00002aaab8c7a800 JavaThread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[glassfish-web]]" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28824, stack(0x000000004a413000,0x000000004a914000)]
  0x00002aaab899d800 JavaThread "deployment-jar-scanner" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28823, stack(0x0000000049f12000,0x000000004a413000)]
  0x000000000c57f800 JavaThread "transaction-manager" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28819, stack(0x0000000048b0e000,0x000000004900f000)]
  0x000000000cfe0800 JavaThread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28818, stack(0x000000004860d000,0x0000000048b0e000)]
  0x00002aaab4343000 JavaThread "Thread-21" [_thread_blocked, id=28817, stack(0x000000004810c000,0x000000004860d000)]
  0x000000000cfdf000 JavaThread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28816, stack(0x0000000047c0b000,0x000000004810c000)]
  0x00002aaab4715800 JavaThread "Thread-18" [_thread_blocked, id=28815, stack(0x000000004770a000,0x0000000047c0b000)]
  0x000000000cfe1800 JavaThread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28814, stack(0x0000000047209000,0x000000004770a000)]
  0x000000000c88b000 JavaThread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28813, stack(0x0000000046d08000,0x0000000047209000)]
  0x00002aaab897e000 JavaThread "Thread-14" [_thread_blocked, id=28812, stack(0x0000000046807000,0x0000000046d08000)]
  0x000000000ce69000 JavaThread "Grizzly-kernel-thread(1)" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28811, stack(0x0000000046306000,0x0000000046807000)]
  0x00002aaab897d000 JavaThread "Thread-9" [_thread_blocked, id=28810, stack(0x0000000045e05000,0x0000000046306000)]
  0x000000000cb96800 JavaThread "Thread-7" [_thread_blocked, id=28809, stack(0x0000000045904000,0x0000000045e05000)]
  0x00002aaab895f800 JavaThread "Thread-5" [_thread_blocked, id=28808, stack(0x0000000045403000,0x0000000045904000)]
  0x00002aaab8969000 JavaThread "pool-1-thread-1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28807, stack(0x0000000044f02000,0x0000000045403000)]
  0x00002aaab8641000 JavaThread "FelixStartLevel" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28806, stack(0x0000000044500000,0x0000000044a01000)]
  0x000000000beff000 JavaThread "FelixDispatchQueue" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28805, stack(0x0000000044a01000,0x0000000044f02000)]
  0x00002aaab419f800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28801, stack(0x0000000043efe000,0x00000000443ff000)]
  0x00002aaab419d800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28800, stack(0x0000000043dfd000,0x0000000043efe000)]
=>0x00002aaab4198000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=28799, stack(0x0000000043cfc000,0x0000000043dfd000)]
  0x00002aaab40ee000 JavaThread "MultiThreadedHttpConnectionManager cleanup" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28796, stack(0x00000000437fb000,0x0000000043cfc000)]
  0x00002aaab4003800 JavaThread "AD Thread Pool-Global1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28795, stack(0x00000000432fa000,0x00000000437fb000)]
  0x00002aaab400d800 JavaThread "AD Thread Pool-Global0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28794, stack(0x0000000042df9000,0x00000000432fa000)]
  0x000000000b88e000 JavaThread "AD Thread-Metric Reporter0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28793, stack(0x00000000428f8000,0x0000000042df9000)]
  0x000000000b857000 JavaThread "AD Thread-Config Poller" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28792, stack(0x00000000415ec000,0x0000000041aed000)]
  0x000000000b7b3800 JavaThread "Thread-0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28791, stack(0x00000000410eb000,0x00000000415ec000)]
  0x000000000b5ef000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28790, stack(0x0000000040bea000,0x00000000410eb000)]
  0x000000000b5a0000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28789, stack(0x00000000423f7000,0x00000000428f8000)]
  0x000000000b59e000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=28788, stack(0x0000000041ef6000,0x00000000423f7000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000b596000 VMThread [stack: 0x0000000040070000,0x0000000040171000] [id=28787]
  0x00002aaab41a4000 WatcherThread [stack: 0x00000000443ff000,0x0000000044500000] [id=28803]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 937216K, used 6414K [0x00000007a2400000, 0x00000007e0c00000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 845888K, 0% used [0x00000007a2400000,0x00000007a2a43ad8,0x00000007d5e10000)
  from space 91328K, 0% used [0x00000007db2d0000,0x00000007db2d0000,0x00000007e0c00000)
  to   space 86784K, 0% used [0x00000007d5e10000,0x00000007d5e10000,0x00000007db2d0000)
 PSOldGen        total 912576K, used 467925K [0x0000000718c00000, 0x0000000750730000, 0x00000007a2400000)
  object space 912576K, 51% used [0x0000000718c00000,0x00000007354f55a0,0x0000000750730000)
 PSPermGen       total 94720K, used 94326K [0x00000006e6c00000, 0x00000006ec880000, 0x0000000718c00000)
  object space 94720K, 99% used [0x00000006e6c00000,0x00000006ec81d9b0,0x00000006ec880000)

Code Cache  [0x00002aaaaeb21000, 0x00002aaaaf8c1000, 0x00002aaab1b21000)
 total_blobs=4170 nmethods=3358 adapters=762 free_code_cache=35382Kb largest_free_block=36057856


Memory: 4k page, physical 4043424k(265500k free), swap 4095992k(2992388k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (21.0-b17) for linux-amd64 JRE (1.7.0-b147), built on Jun 27 2011 01:30:59 by "java_re" with gcc 4.3.0 20080428 (Red Hat 4.3.0-8)

time: Mon Dec 17 01:39:09 2012
elapsed time: 768 seconds
```

Comment: I suggest googling with this: `libjvm.so+0x64e744` since this is specific to the location within the shared library where the error occurred.

Comment: You appear to be running Glassfish.  If this is for a production server, I would strongly consider using a JVM release officially blessed by the release team.

Comment: AFAIK build 147 was one of the first releases. I suggest trying Java 7 update 10 as it's quite likely this is a bug which has been fixed.

Comment: peter Update to  java7 update 10 ,but i am  still getting the exception

Comment: I suggest googling this : problematic frame   PhaseIdealLoop::clone_loop since maybe other have had problems with that method (doing something similar helped me anyway)

Answer (score 8):

This is solved by adding   -XX:-UseLoopPredicate
http://java.dzone.com/articles/dont-use-java-7-are-you

Answer (score 2):

This indicates an error in the JVM itself.

First you need to be absolutely certain your hardware - notably your memory - is in order.  Run memcheck to find out (the easiest way may be to boot on a Ubuntu install media, and pick it from the boot menu).

Fix any hardware issues found.

If problem persists, ensure you are running the latest version of the Java distribution you are using.  If you run OpenJDK consider downloading an Oracle build, and vice versa.  If you do not need 64-bit consider using a 32-bit JVM.

Comment: I would qualify "This indicates an error in the JVM itself" with "probably". It could, for example, be some JNI code that has run previously and has corrupted some memory (e.g. via a dangling pointer).

Comment: @NPE please examine the call stack - we appear to be inside the C2 compiler in the JVM.

Comment: No question about that. My point is that, with memory problems, the culprit can be well removed from the point of the crash. I think you're probably right that it's a JVM bug, but we don't know this with any degree of certainty.

Answer (score 1):

[This link](http://weblogs.java.net/blog/kohsuke/archive/2009/02/crash_course_on.html) is very useful when diagnosing crash dumps. However, if you're not using native code I would suggest upgrading (or perhaps even downgrading) your JVM to avoid this issue. That's often the fastest way to resolve such issues.

Answer (score 0):

The crash is in the jvm JIT compiler. You could try turning off the compiler to see if it helps to diagnose the issue.
Use the -Xint option.

Answer (score 0):

I referred this link: 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/396525/eclipse-crashing-on-startup

It says:

To solve this issue, try to put this line (slightly different from -Dorg...):

*org.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla*

at the end of this file

eclipse/configuration/config.ini

Comment: Hi, do you have solution for  netbeans ?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar case and I could repair changing my from Oracle SDK to OpenSDK, and verify if your library is compaible with your java version

Answer (score 0):

It may not a problem from your JVM；
If you're using native code in your Java code, you should confirm the parameter list of Java function is consistent with your native function.