# Java Runtime Environment SIGSEGV error on server startup

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

I'm using java version "1.7.0_45" with eclipse kepler and on server startup I'm getting the below error log.

Although I've found several posts[[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19332489/how-to-fix-failed-to-write-core-dump-core-dumps-have-been-disabled-error-whil), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13912090/a-fatal-error-has-been-detected-by-the-java-runtime-environment-sigsegv-0xb-a)] regarding the same issue, I've tried everything from adding -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla, -XX:LoopUnrollLimit=1 and ulimit -c unlimited but nothing worked for me.

Is there any other work around ?

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x0000000000000000, pid=7084, tid=139749936641792
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_45-b18) (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.45-b08 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x0000000000000000
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
#
```

Comment: Oh man, SIGSEGV. Sounds like Java is breaking on the native C side.

Comment: Agreed, this seems more like a problem with your core Java Runtime Environment installation, not your Java code. Try running `java -version` from a terminal/command prompt and see if it still gives an error. You might try [reinstalling your JDK](https://www.java.com/en/download/manual.jsp).

Comment: Are  you sure you have JDK installed?

Comment: Grab the 64 bit version of eclipse.

Comment: SIGSEV means that your program is producing a so called segmentation fault. Writing over array boundaries, OR invalid memory addresses, etc... So I think you have to  re install eclipse first and then see if you have to reinstall java and eclipse both... if the first wont work for you.

Comment: @sivatumma turn that into an answer ;)

Comment: @ajp15243 I've already checked everything, java is installed properly.  And I've posted the java version as well, I got it from java -version only :P

Comment: @Esko Does that makes sense to have such an error log if JDK wouldn't be there ?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch I'm using the 64 bit version only.

Comment: Are you sure you have the 64 bit version of eclipse? Does eclipse -clean help?

Answer (score 1):

SIGSEV means that your program is producing a so called segmentation fault. Writing over array boundaries, OR invalid memory addresses, etc... So I think you have to re install eclipse first and then see if you have to reinstall java and eclipse both... if the first wont work for you.

I am not sure if this is the correct guess, I hope no one downvotes this...

Comment: Thanks for responding ! But I'm already aware of what SIGSEGV means ! And I've already tried those reinstalling and restarting things.

Comment: ohh... okay. take it easy. Normally I too have some issues like this. My eclipse after a while of working, exits itself with a jvm exit code 1... (It was due to the fact I am working on a 2 gb RAM PC. and my workspace contains about 20 maven projects... _and .m2 repo, you know!!_. The edge is that I observe this only when chrome is running adjacently, though... hmmm... I don't know the exact reason...

Comment: Haha, thanks for providing the info :) But I'm running on 8GB, 3.2GHz and i3. Also there is just one project, so I don't think that could be the case.

Comment: So btw, did you check with permissions ? I often try `sudo chown myself` before running these things. some times, they work with `sudo -i` after all of the time waste exploration.

Comment: @dShringi did you manage to get a core dump, and checked what the backtrace shows inside GDB ?

Comment: @dShringi perhaps this is the bug hitting you already - https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=392967

Comment: @tuxdna Yes I got the core dump but I've never tried GDB. So I'm unable to get it :P Its pretty much the similar log from the link you gave, but it shouldn't be there if its fixed as I'm using the latest version.

Comment: @DShringi: Can you try GDB and share the backtrace so as to narrow down our search ? :-)

Comment: As an aside comment to @sivatumma: Running an IDE like Eclipse at the same time as Chrome on a machine with 2GB of RAM is going to cause a lot of choking, pausing, and lockups, as both of those apps are very memory-hungry and will eat that amount of RAM up in an instant.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error while I started netbeans in Ubuntu 13.04. I fixed it with

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-7-jdk
```

Try and see if it works.